# Best method to search on table with self join

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, fluent-nhibernate, sql-server-2012

I have classes like these in c#:

```
public class Family
{
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Family Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Family> Childrens { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Produt> Produts { get; set; }
}

public class Produt
{
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Family Family { get; set; }
}
```

After this, I did the mappings:

```
public partial class FamilyMap : AbstractEntityMap<Family>
{
    public FamilyMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Description).Length(100);
        References(x => x.Parent, "IdParent");
        HasMany(x => x.Childrens).KeyColumns.Add("IdParent");
        HasMany(x=>x.Produts);
    }
}

public partial class ProdutMap : AbstractEntityMap<Produt>
{
    public ProdutMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Description).Length(100);
        References(x => x.Family);
    }
}
```

Imagine a Family with a lot of childrens and each children with a lot of childrens... What the best method to know the produts that belong to parent with id=3, for example...

P.S. Id is in the AbstractEntityMap.

Answer (score 0):

use recursive With statement at SQL side